# Simple computational biology project for AP Biology class. Ideas?

Tags: evolution, bioinformatics, species-identification, phylogenetics

Our teacher assigned us a project to do with an extremely open-ended prompt and it should be completed within a month. 
I was planning on doing something related to computation and evolution in terms of biology although I'm not really sure where to start. I say simple because I'm not a professional programmer, rather, extremely interested in the field and I hope to use this as an opportunity to stretch by skills. 
Any ideas on a project or where to start would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, Biology.SE is not a forum, and your question is quite opinion-based. From the [help/dont-ask], *`If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.`* However, simple Google searches will turn up plenty of hits for project ideas as well as sites where this type of discussion *would* be on-topic, such as Reddit or Quora. Good luck!

Comment: This could be an appreciated discussion at [Reddit bioinformatics](https://www.reddit.com/r/bioinformatics/). Ask where to start, what are easy to use and quick tools, and how to get something meaningful out of the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BLAST or NCBI resources to do an analysis of something like the duplication of a gene in the HIV virus, for example. If you're looking for a place to start, I would recommend just learning the NCBI database resources.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Ham Radio suggested, checking out [Galaxy](https://usegalaxy.org/) might not be a bad idea for doing any sort of computation/analysis that would otherwise have to be done on the command line. In particular, check out tools for sequence alignment (BWA and Bowtie), genome assembly (Velvet, Spades, IDBA-UD), and variant analysis (Freebayes, Mpileup, GATK). Good luck!